# Как делать много запросов через одно соединение XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Может я не полностью понимаю, что происходит "внутри" XMLHttpRequest, но мне надо как-то сделать много запросов не создавая каждый раз новое подключение. Использую стандартный набор вызовов:

```
function GetFrame(){
    var DataRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    DataRequest.open("POST", "/index.php", true);
    DataRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    DataRequest.send("Data="+Data);
    DataRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(DataRequest.readyState === 4){
            if(DataRequest.status === 200){
                if(DataRequest.responseText.length > 0){
                    Stream.src = DataRequest.responseText;
                }
            } 
        }
    };
}
```

Всё работает, картинки меняются (идёт видео), но **если посмотреть в файрволе на соединения - исходящие растут как снежный ком**. Клиенты, которые эти картинки отправляют, написаны на плюсах - зацеплены сокетом за сервер и отправляют поток без нарастания соединений, а веб-интерфейс, где осуществляется просмотр, обращается к серверу AJAX-ами. Пытался вынести в глобальные пременные `var DataRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();` - не помогло.

**Можно как-то поддерживать соединение открытым и слать сколько угодно запросов по нему при помощи XMLHttpRequest?** Или обязательно переписывать код на веб-сокеты?

*PS: В конфиге apache - KeepAliveTimeout 86400 (сутки), MaxKeepAliveRequests 0 (не ограничено)*

Comment: Может, попробовать добавить `DataRequest.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close')`?

Comment: Не-а, не помогает :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соединениями к серверу управляет браузер. Вы не можете управлять ими из скрипта. Но вы можете быть уверенными, что если на момент начала запроса есть "ждущее" соединение - браузер догадается использовать его повторно. Ну, если не заглючит. Но если это баг браузера - то вы его тем более не почините из javascript.

Накапливаться соединения могут по разным причинам. Самая вероятная - вы делаете много **одновременных** запросов. У вас `GetFrame()` никак не сообщает об окончании запроса - а значит, их может стать слишком много попросту из-за медленной связи. Посмотрите в консоли браузера сколько запросов активно в каждый момент времени.

Если вам нужно узнать как дождаться окончания запроса перед тем как делать следующий - вам в вот этот вопрос: [*"Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?"*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/178779)

Если ничего не поможет - попробуйте вместо apache использовать nginx (или поставить nginx перед apache). Nginx лучше работает со множественными соединениями и не боится их количества :)

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` - не умеет ждать и отправляется каждый раз когда вы вызываете `send`.
Если вы пытаетесь сделать какой-то онлайн интерфейс или чат, советую смотреть в сторону протокола `ws://`

[**RFC 6455**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455%5D)
Можно оттолкнуться к примеру от этого [чата](http://www.saaraan.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket/)

Comment: К сожалению есть чёткая установка - никаких php-демонов. А может этот запрос можно как-то принудительно разрывать после ответа сервера, не меняя конфиги apache? А то и сервер периодически падает с логом "server reached maxclients setting"

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` - так не умеет, я не пойму раз у вас уже подцеплен сокет к серверу, то зачем вы вообще HTTP юзаете? Когда у вас уже есть место где ответ лежит  -  на счет ошибки `server reached maxclients setting` - видимо,  что-то с настройками самого web сервера apache.

Comment: Серверный скрипт просто обрабатывает POST-запросы и работает с shared memory. Клиент на С++ отправляет запросы с данными и всеми необходимыми заголовками, но он "висит" на одном сокете. А веб-интерфейс, где просматривается контент, присланный C++-клиентами, плодит кучу соединений AJAX-ами, и, поскольку на сервере KeepAlive огормный (чтобы клиенты не отваливались), эти AJAX-запросы висят мёртвыми на сервере после отработки. Может как-то можно сообщить серверу, что после ответа на AJAX надо прибить соединение? Или на JS можно отправить POST через сокеты не переписывая серверный скрипт?

Comment: По сути если вы используете в обвертке `readystatechange` то запрос сам убивается, а если не используете, то можно просто сделать `xhr.abort()` - чтобы убить запрос. Но мне не понятно, если у вас уже есть клиент который висит на сокете у сервера, то для чего вы используете HTTP, когда можно получить ответ от сокета?

Comment: Клиенты шлют кадры с камеры. У каждого клиента свой идентификатор, который отображается в списке клиентов в веб интерфейсе. Под каждого клиента сервер выделяет блок распределяемой памяти, где происходит перезапись кадров при каждом получении данных. При выборе клиента из списка в веб-интерфейсе ajax обращается по id клиента, который служит ключом к shmop_open, и получает поток кадров из этой области памяти (в приведенном коде Data - это id клиента). Таких запросов из веб интерфейса идёт 25 штук в секунду, и каждый плодит новое подключение (на cpp-клиентах такого нет - там 1 сокет).

Comment: Ну я вам и объясняю, что нельзя так сделать 1 соединении с ожиданием без ws или wss протокола. Исходя из этого вы получаете бесконечный пулл `соединение > запрос`, `соединение -> запрос`, а не так как на сокете `соединение` -> `запрос, -> запрос`.

Comment: Самое интересное, что на localhost соединения не накапливаются, проблема только с реальным сервером...  А я могу отправить POST-запрос на веб-сокетах в JS, без изменения серверного скрипта?

Comment: Протокол HTTP является изначально синхронным, то есть построенным по модели запрос<>ответ, а WebSocket - это асинхронное взаимодействие клиента и сервера в реальном времени, в отличие от `XMLHttpRequest` - `WebSocket` устанавливает одно TCP-соединение. При этом открытое не активное соединение не кушает ресурсы. Вы конечно можете сделать двунаправленную связью, используя запросы `XMLHttpRequest`. Но! - это будет очень медленно, так как каждый раз придется создавать новое TCP-соединение для каждого запроса.